# Downloading Met Office Datapoint tiles for specific region

Tags: wmts, request, inspire

Does anyone know how to use the Met Office Datapoint API to download tiled imagery?

There are some "detailed instructions" [here](https://www.metoffice.gov.uk/services/data/datapoint/inspire-layers-detailed-documentation), but it is not clear how to relate tile coordinates to real world coordinates.

For example, to download a tile of rainfall radar imagery, I can use a request like

```
http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/inspire/view/wmts?REQUEST=gettile
&LAYER=Precipitation_Rate&FORMAT=image/png&TILEMATRIXSET=EPSG:4258
&TILEMATRIX=EPSG:4258:0&TILEROW=0&TILECOL=0&DIM_RUN=2013-11-20T03:00:00Z
&DIM_FORECAST=%2B9&key=<API key>
```

This is fine for zoom level 0 (as there is only one tile at this level), but what I can't figure out is which row and column numbers to use to get a specific tile.

More information about the service can be found using the `getcapabilities` command (you need to register to get an API key first).

```
http://datapoint.metoffice.gov.uk/public/data/inspire/view/wmts?REQUEST=getcapabilities
&key=<APIKEY>
```

It gives information for each available spatial reference and zoom level, for example this is EPSG:4258 level 9:

```
<TileMatrix>
    <ows:Identifier>EPSG:4258:9</ows:Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>128062.35453175165</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>-10.67 71.05</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>512</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>512</MatrixHeight>
</TileMatrix>
```

I can turn each tile into a GDAL dataset then use the heights and widths to place it in the grid. All I need to do is add a geotransform - I've got the top left coordinates, but can't work out the pixel resolution.

Presumably I can do something with the scale denominator, but I'm a but stumped.

Maybe I'm barking up the wrong tree and there is a better way to do it. Can anyone help?

Comment: looks like a standard wmts service

Comment: Correct. I've never used one before though, more of a desktop person.

Comment: Found it! Looks like https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323400/48071 is the answer I was after.

Comment: Fair enough, this is a duplicate. "wmts" was the search term that I was missing.